# Need to setup heroku app on my domain server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, bluehost

Let me explain my needs.

I have an apps on heroku.com

Now I have my own domain on bluehost.com

Need to setup these heroku app on my domain.

means when I visit on mydomain.com url, its use heroku app not redirect on just work with my mydomain.com links.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Heroku provides [detailed docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains) on how to setup custom domains for your apps.

In a nutshell, you'll want to setup a `www` subdomain, redirect your naked domain to the `www` subdomain (`mydomain.com` -> `www.mydomain.com`), add a CNAME to the `www` subdomain pointing at your app (`www.mydomain.com` -> `myapp.heroku.com`), and add the `www` subdomain to the Heroku app (`heroku domains:add www.mydomain.com`).

There are other ways to set up a custom domain on a Heroku app, which the docs go into detail about. But the above is the most common.